# implementation of queue using two stacks

Tags: c, stack

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct stack
{
   int top,size,top1;
   int *arr;
};
int isempty(struct stack *ptr)
{
   if(ptr->top==-1){return 1;}
   else{return 0;}
}
int isfull(struct stack *ptr)
{
   if(ptr->top==ptr->size-1){return 1;}
   else{return 0;}
}
int push(struct stack *ptr, int data)
{
   if(isfull(ptr)){printf("Stack is Full\n");}
   else{
      ptr->top++;
      ptr->arr[ptr->top]=data;
   }
}
int pop(struct stack *ptr)
{
   if(isempty(ptr)){printf("Stack is empty\n");}
   else{
      int a=ptr->arr[ptr->top];
         ptr->top--;
         return a;
   }
}
int pop2(struct stack *ptr)
{
   struct stack *lol;
   printf("!");
   lol->top1=-1;
   printf("!");
   lol->size=100;
   printf("!");
   lol->arr=(int*)malloc(lol->size*sizeof(int));
}
int main()
{
   struct stack *ptr;
   ptr->top=-1;
   ptr->size=100;
   ptr->arr=(int*)malloc(ptr->size*sizeof(int));
   push(ptr,1);
   push(ptr,2);
   push(ptr,3);
   push(ptr,4);
   push(ptr,5);
   pop2(ptr);
   printf("%d ",pop(ptr));
   printf("%d ",pop(ptr));
   printf("%d ",pop(ptr));
   printf("%d ",pop(ptr));
   printf("%d ",pop(ptr));
}
```

i am trying to run this code but dont konw why but in function pop2 the second and third printf are not working or in other terms pop2 is not working. it is not throwing any error but just stops after sometime. if i remove pop2 than the whole code is working properly

Comment: Consider using [realloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) and [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html). Read the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), to use as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`....) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/)....). You may want to use  [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and should read about [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)

Comment: `lol->top1 = -1;` is instant undefined behavior. Look at the code. The pointer `lol` is declared with indeterminate value then dereferenced just two lines later.  (and throughout the rest of the function). You make the same mistake in `main` with `ptr`. In short, this looks like the fundamental problem is you don't know how to use pointers and dynamic memory, at least not fully. Any decent beginners reference text on the language will cover this in detail.

Comment: @WhozCraig but i did the same for ptr in int main

Comment: @BharatGoyal Re. `"but i did the same for ptr in int main"`: it's undefined behaviour -- anything can happen.  Unfortunately that 'anything' includes it *seemingly* working in one place but not in another.

Comment: This code has a *lot* of undefined behavior, the incorrect pointer and memory use being just one part of it. `push`, for example, claims it returns an `int`, but in reality make no actual attempt to do so. `pop` claims it returns an `int`, but makes no effort to do so when the stack is empty.  Besides the broken pointer usage, `pop2` claims it returns `int`, but never does so whatsoever.